# Flutter easy_localization Localization key not found

Tags: flutter, dart, localization

I have tried implementing [easy_localization](https://pub.dev/packages/easy_localization) in my app. For that I have added this folder structure:

[image]

For testing I am only using German. My JSON-File looks like this:

```
{
    "myGenerealConditionHeader": "Mein Allgemeinzustand"
}
```

My `main`:

```
void main() async {

  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(
    EasyLocalization(
      supportedLocales: [Locale('de', 'DE')],
      path: 'assets/translations',
      fallbackLocale: Locale('de', 'DE'),
      child: App(userId: userId),
    ),
  );
}
```

And I am using it like this:

```
Text(
  'myGenerealConditionHeader'.tr(),
),
```

But Flutter is complaining with this `error`:

> [ Easy Localization] [WARNING] Localization key [myGenerealConditionHeader] not found

What am I missing here?

Comment: Did you add the file path in pubspec.yaml assets

Comment: @7mada yes. I can use the package.

Comment: I guess you just need a restart then, as what I can see nothing should go wrong.

Comment: Use `Locale('de')` instead of `Locale('de', 'DE')` in latest version of this package. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the plugin is unable to find the reference name on the configured locale. This usually happens when the locale String is newly added. To rebuild the references, run `flutter clean` on your terminal, then run the app again.

Comment: This did not solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used LocaleKeys.example.tr().tr() by mistake. Check your keys!